# Why do I need to redo the Google oAuth process even though I have the refresh token

Tags: php, laravel, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have a laravel app where i need to import events from Google Calendar API. I am working on the app on my local computer. I have read that if i have the refresh token, the user no more needs to regrant the access each time. In my case, I always need to redo the operation even if i have the refresh token and generate an access token each time it's expired, here is the code:

```
  $user = auth()->user();

  // Check if the user has a stored access token
  if (!$user->google_access_token) {
      return redirect()->route('events.index')->with('message', 'Google Calendar access not 
  granted');
  }

  // Create a Google Client instance and set the access token
  $client = new Google_Client();
  
  $client->setAccessToken($user->google_access_token);


     // Check if the access token is expired
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      // Use the refresh token to obtain a new access token
      $refreshToken = $user->google_refresh_token;
      $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshToken);
      // Update the user's access token in the database
      //dd($client->getAccessToken()['access_token']);
      $user->update(['google_access_token' => $client->getAccessToken()['access_token']]);
      $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()['access_token']);
      
  }

  // Create a new instance of the Google Calendar service
  $calendarService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

  // Set the calendar ID (usually 'primary' for the authenticated user's primary calendar)
  $calendarId = 'primary';

        // Fetch events from the Google Calendar
        $eventsAPI = $calendarService->events->listEvents($calendarId);
```

First, I have my app under 'Test mode' in Google Cloud Console, I thought the problem was coming from it. I switch to developement mode and yet still facing the same issue. My refresh_token and access_token are store in the database.

Comment: "redo the operation"  What operation?  are you saying you need to click on the consent screen again?

Comment: Have you debugged these two lines
 $user->update(['google_access_token' => $client->getAccessToken()['access_token']]);
 $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()['access_token']);

You are calling thse $client->getAccessToken()['access_token']] two times check if the value isn't changed while storing and setting access token.

Comment: Yes the value isn't changed, both access_token and refresh_token are stored in database, but after like one hour i always need to regrant access through the consent screen